# Fiction Book Who Am I? #4 (Guess the book too!)

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

Oh no.... I stumbled upon another of these, and it asks for the person AND where the story left off! But I suppose I have to give it to you...

> When I was the spry age of eight,
> My house, or shop, burned down that date,
> With Esperanza gone, it was that the hopping came...
>
> The homes came one by one, the same,
> I was so "bad" I ran from them,
> But I had to sleep under a rotting bridge to shield...
>
> I got sent into Nevada,
> It was as bad as all nada,
> And then I met my friends, to come for all my life...
>
> I got a ride into the air,
> And passed over Delaware,
> A car crash happened next, the kind you wouldn't think...
>
> I learned of the woodlands' curse,
> I made the quest, but not as first,
> Another crash and then, hopeless as it may be...
>
> We pushed west, hardened as three,
> But I had serious jealousy,
> We finally succeeded, and then came back to camp...
>
> And that's where this story ends,
> I haven't finished living, and,
> Tell me what time I'm in, and also my name, please...

So who am I, and where did I leave off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer

The character is

> **Leo Valdez**

from

> ***Heroes of Olympus***

## Reasoning

> His mother died in the workshop/house fire. Also, it mentions camp like Camp Half-Blood and Camp Jupiter.Leo was also jealous of Frank because he fell for Hazel.Finally, he died defeating Gaea and cures himself with the Physician’s Cure. He was not finished living.